# Convert Mesh.SetVertices() to Mesh.SetVertexBufferParams() and Mesh.SetVertexBufferData()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to improve the performance of some mesh generation, and so I'd like to change from using SetVertices() to the SetVertexBufferParam/Data pattern. This is what I have:

```
// verts is a NativeArray<float3>
// numVerts is the length of verts
Mesh mesh = new Mesh();

// this works and creates a series of flat faces
mesh.SetVertices(verts);

// this creates a mesh but it's very wrong
mesh.SetVertexBufferParams(numVerts,
  new VertexAttributeDescriptor(VertexAttribute.Position, VertexAttributeFormat.Float32, 3),
  new VertexAttributeDescriptor(VertexAttribute.Normal, VertexAttributeFormat.Float32, 3));
mesh.SetVertexBufferData(verts, 0, 0, numVerts);

// afterwards I set indices, norms, etc.
```

Desired result vs result using SetVertexBufferData:

[image: Desired result]

[image: Result using SetVertexBufferData]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Note that I only use SetVertices OR the SetVertexBufferParam/Data portions of code. I don't run both at once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`Mesh.SetVertexBufferData`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.SetVertexBufferData.html) and in particular also [`VertexAttributeDescriptor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.VertexAttributeDescriptor.html)

Usually you use your own Vertex struct. You are passing a layout

```
new VertexAttributeDescriptor(VertexAttribute.Position, VertexAttributeFormat.Float32, 3),
new VertexAttributeDescriptor(VertexAttribute.Normal, VertexAttributeFormat.Float32, 3)
```

which would expect an input struct composed of 6 x Float32 like e.g.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct YourVertex
{
    public Vector3 position;
    public Vector3 normal;
}
```

but actually you only provide the `float3` data which is only enough for

```
new VertexAttributeDescriptor(VertexAttribute.Position, VertexAttributeFormat.Float32, 3)
```

In the native array you basically just get

```
float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, ...
```

and it is the job of the layout do define how exactly those are supposed to be interpreted. So since you tell the layout to expect a 3 x Float32 position + a 3x Float32 normal it is trying to apply always 3 floats to the position and 3 floats to the normal

=> these 3 floats belonging actually to the next vertex get kinda "lost" / applied incorrectly as normal

Comment: Ah, I removed the Normal descriptor and now it accepts a native array of float3. I’ll be sure to keep this in mind if I need to add it back. Cheers!